# How to overwrite a file to remove a comment block

Tags: python, file, overwrite

I am writing a python script that goes through each file searching for a file header comment block and trying too remove it . That looks something like this..

```
# comment 
# comment 
# comment 
# comment
```

I have 200 + files to go through and thought it would be fun to learn how to write scripts in python because I am fairly new to programming.

here is the code i have thus far

```
with open(filename, "r+") as f:
    commentBlock = """
    # comment
    # comment
    # comment
    # comment
    """
    lines = commentBlock.splitlines('\n')
    
   

     for i in f:
            for j in lines:
                    if (i != j): 
                        f.write(i)
```

NOTE: that the format of the comment block is the same for all files, so i thought this approach would work, but it does not do what i thought is would have which was overwrite the file, only with the lines that don't match (because the comment block would match). I only want just that specific comment block, i don't want every comment line to be removed.

I tried to change the "r+" to "w+" but then the file that was passed it became empty.

Answer (score 0):

The following code eliminates each line that has as first characters `# comment` or `"""` in the file `"other_file_where_you_delete.py"`:

```
with open("other_file_where_you_delete.py", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("other_file_where_you_delete.py", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip().startswith("# comment") or line.strip().startswith('"""'):
            pass
        else:
            f.write(line)
```

If you want to do this in multiple files you need to loop over the list of files that you want to modify.

##### Note:

You have to specify the full path of files that are not in the same directory of this script.

Comment: Won't this also delete comment every where in the file? I just need that specific comment block deleted only?